# MYSQL query for specific ROW

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, function

I have a table in MYSQL called "statetable" that has the following Columns: `"STATE", "Num", "PCT"`

I want to run a query where it returns just the data for a specific state. I believe the right code is:

```
SELECT * FROM statetable WHERE State = "California"
```

However, I am doing this in a PHP script that will go on my wordpress site.

The code in my custom php template looks like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:displayresults
*/
get_header();
?>

<?php

global $wpdb;

$california = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM statetable WHERE State = "California"; ")
print_r($california);

?>
```

I keep getting a blank page, not sure what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An editor with proper syntax highlighting would have shown you the problem immediately. As does the syntax highlighting here ,-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite to

```
$california = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM `statetable` WHERE `State` = 'California'");
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. As you probably know, this spits out a rather messy output, it looks like:
stdClass Object ( [State] => California [num-ASN] => 5004645 [pct-ASN] => 13.3% )

I would like to place this into a table. Any suggestions? Sorry if this is beyond the scope of my original question!

Answer (score 0):

you have double quotes in your string!

```
$california = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM statetable WHERE State = 'California'; ");
```

This should work